# php complicated boolean expression

Tags: php, boolean, expression, logical-operators, evaluation

I went to a job interview yesterday and I got the following test question:

What is the output of this logic:

```
if(TRUE && FALSE AND TRUE OR 1 || TRUE && ((TRUE || FALSE) || FALSE)) {
   PRINT "A";
} 
else print "B";
```

I had to evaluate the result in my head, which I could not do.

How would you go about this?

Comment: why dont you just create a short php script and test your homework?

Comment: Check the PHP [operators precedence](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.precedence.php)

Comment: I could not create a script as I had to answer the question on paper. There was no access to a computer on this job interview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The expression has in the middle, outside any parenthesis: `OR 1 ||`. It does not matter how the left and right expressions evaluate, at the end they are combined with `OR TRUE` and the result is always `TRUE`.

The printed value is `A`.

Comment: I had one more look to the php operator precedence page and now I think that because the && operator has the highest perecedence it will be first converted to something like this: (TRUE) && (FALSE AND TRUE OR 1 || TRUE) && ((TRUE || FALSE) || FALSE) and because the content of all these three paranthesized expressons are TRUE this is why the result will be true.

Comment: The main point is that it is very tricky to figure this out on a paper without computer. I think it is very very stupid to give this kind of question on a paper on a job interview. I have never come across an expression like this, or anything even close to this, on a real life php program in my ten years of experience.

Comment: The parenthesis `((TRUE || FALSE) || FALSE)` evaluates to `TRUE`. The expression becomes `((TRUE && FALSE) AND TRUE) OR (1 || (TRUE && TRUE))`; I added parenthesis to show the evaluation order. `1 || anything` is `TRUE`, `(...) OR TRUE` is `TRUE`.

Comment: Indeed, it's not a good interview question. I think I never wrote an expression half as complicated and in the last years I avoid writing more than one boolean operator in an expression; having more makes the code hard to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The result will print `A`.

It will go in `if`

**Explanation:**

TRUE && FALSE AND TRUE OR 1 || TRUE && ((TRUE || FALSE) || FALSE)

TRUE && FALSE -> FALSE -> LETS NAME IT FALSE(1)

FALSE(1) AND TRUE  -> FALSE -> LETS NAME IT FALSE(2)

FALSE(2) OR 1 -> TRUE -> LETS NAME IT TRUE(3)

------ Now second part ------------

TRUE --> TRUE (4)

((TRUE || FALSE)  -> TRUE (5)

TRUE (5)  || FALSE --> TRUE (6)

NOW

combining two expressions:

TRUE(3) || TRUE(6) is `TRUE`

Comment: `TRUE && FALSE -> TRUE -> LETS NAME IT TRUE(1)` true and false is false

Comment: Hmm, updating answer/

Comment: you missed `TRUE (4) && TRUE(6)`

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the `OR 1`
As this is on the... well let's call it top level it will be true OR anything else... which results in "true" ;)